# congruence solution

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Determine is, in general, true or false. Recall that a universal statement is true if it is true for all possible cases while it is false if there is even one counterexample. Be prepared to prove that your answer is correct by supplying a proof or counterexample, whichever is appropriate

If $(\frac{a}{b})=-1$ and $(\frac{b}{q})=-1$ then $x^2 \equiv ab \pmod{pq}$ where $p$ and $q$ are odd prime has a solution.

Solution:

$(\frac{a}{b})=-1$

$a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$

$a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} +1 =pk$

$(\frac{b}{q})=-1$

$b^{\frac{q-1}{2}}\equiv -1 \pmod{q}$

$b^{\frac{q-1}{2}} +1 =qk$

Now multiplying both the equation we get

$[a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} +1] [b^{\frac{q-1}{2}} +1 ]=pqk$

$(ab)^{\frac{pq-1}{2}}    -1=pqk$

$x^2 \equiv ab \pmod{pq}$ has solution

> Could you check it for me please is it correct or not?

Comment: Please check the statement. The prime $p$ is not even mentioned in the conditions.

Comment: You *really* should follow the directions of the site to write mathematics clearly. As it is, your post is hard to read and understand.

Comment: yes p is odd pirme